# Skip NaN values when integrating using numpy trapz

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, nan, numerical-integration

I am using the numpy function `trapz` to perform integration. Some of my arrays have `NaN` values and I'd like the trapezoidal algorithm to simply "skip" over those values when computing the trapezoids rather than returning `NaN` for that slice. Is there a simple way to accomplish this? I've looked at scipy's `trapz` function and it doesn't seem to be able to do this either.

Comment: Mask out the NaNs?

Comment: There's a collection of `np.nan...` functions which mask out or replace `nan` values in an array.  Follow their lead.

Comment: Based on tests, I'm not sure it's quite that simple. There are some cases where calling `np.trapz` on an array with NaNs masked out (e.g. with `np.ma.masked_invalid`) produces the same results as with an explicitly compressed array, but it's not always the case - I think it has to do with `trapz`'s assumptions about `x`/`dx`. @fivebyfive please provide an example of your call to the function and an equivalent `for` loop that produces the desired results. Please include example numerical values - a completely executable example.

Comment: I would just use a mask:
`msk1 = np.isfinite(x_arr); msk2 = np.isfinite(y_arr); msk = np.logical_and(msk1, msk2); np.trapezoid(y_arr[msk], x=x_arr[msk])`

Comment: @MattHaberland, I wasn't recommending the `np.ma` tools.  But yes, you do want to 'mask' both the 'x' and 'y' arguments.  The underlying math for `trapz` is pretty simple - just construct trapizoids for all valid points, calculate their areas, and sum.

Comment: @hpaulj sure, rolling your own is easy, too. @AndrewNelson I don't think that solves the problem because it sounds like the user has >1d input ("...rather than returning `NaN` for that slice"), and presumably doesn't want to write a `for` loop. (Also, did you mean `np.logical_or`?) I think @fivebyfive needs to give an example. We are making certain assumptions about what the NaNs mean, and I think that needs to be made explicit.